# I got some news for you - get active!

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**I'm looking for a 6-letter word. Which word?**

---

[image]

```
   AG (swing) x8 →
   O  (present) x1 →
    T (web) x1 →
   U  (legal action) x2 →
  TO  (part of 12") x1 →
   O  (present) x3 →
    T (web) x1 →
   U  (legal action) x4 →
  TO  (part of 12") x1 →
   O  (present) x5 →
    T (web) x1 →
   U  (legal action) x6
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the answer is

> **ADIDAS**

First let's solve the word clues

> swing = **W**AG
>  present = **N**O**W**
>  web = **NE**T
>  legal action = **S**U**E**
>  part of 12" = TO**E** (part of a *foot*)

Now notice that

> The letters we need to fill in, in each clue, are all cardinal directions, in particular **W**, **NW**, **NE**, **SE**, **E**.
>  We must be being directed to draw lines in the grid at the top. Taking the instructions in order (with the multipliers being the number of steps) it looks like we'll have to be able to go at least six steps north and at least nine steps west of our starting point so we should start in the bottom right hand corner.

Using the grid

> Starting at the bottom right node and filling in the path according to the directions gives the following.
>  [image]
>  which looks like the logo for **ADIDAS**

Title

> Adidas is a sportswear manufacturer, so the logo puts one in mind to get active.
>  Also the title contains the word *news* indicating the cardinal directions (N E W S) - thanks OP for pointing this out.

Comment: This is it! Well done. Also in title rot13 (A R J F)

Comment: @Prim3numbah Ah yes, thanks!